# Database structure and relationships

Tags: database, structure

I'm building this gaming portal and I have some database concerns. Currently I have about 10 tables, but I think they will be more than 20 when I'm finished programming. Anyway, I want to create some sort of relationships between the different tables (somewhat like WordPress). That table will hold any relation that one row from table A has to a row in table B. And what I came up with is the following:

table relationships

```
| rs_id | rs_type | rs_alpha | rs_beta |
```

rs_id -> just an id
rs_type -> the type of relation
rs_alpha -> related table #1 and row id
rs_beta -> related table #2 and row id

examples:

```
| 1 | cover | games:153 | images:318 |
| 2 | tag | news:183 | tags:18 |
| 3 | group_admin | users:918 | group:75 |
...
```

This might just do it, but here it comes my concerns:
1. This table is going to grow so fast that in no time there might be over 100,000 rows which will slow the load time.
2. To extract info I'll have to explode every call which might slow down the load time.
3. I might divide table name from id (rs_alpha, rs_beta), yet that might also slow down the load time.

Thank you and I'm open to any other solutions that might be better than this one :)

If you have time you can download my db structure from here to see what it looks like:
demirevdesign.com/public/pcanvil.sql.gz

(The addon_ tables will become the relationships table)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, relationship type itself defines tables involved , so no need in storing table names.
Also, if you refactor your schema and add a common parent table for all entities that might be involved in relationship, you won't need to care about table name at all , you just store id of that new table.

Finally, relationship always has start date and may have end date, I'd suggest adding this attributes to `relationships` table.

As to performance, it's hard to answer without seeing how you are going to query the table. I guess in general partitioning by relationship type column will be beneficial

Comment: I haven't thought that the rs_type might carry the table info. Thanks!
As for the date, I think it is really not important. The relationships table is just to show if one row is connected to another. Still I don't know if what I'm doing here is the best solution. If you have time, please download my database (I added link in my question) and take a glance at it, I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Сър Георги Демирев : I looked on your dump, but it has 15 or so tables, and analyzing them /giving useful recommendations sounds like at least couple hours work, not as a question can be answered in a few minutes... I'd suggest reading http://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/data-model-resource-sample-collection.pdf , it has chapter describing pattern for storing relationship between entities .